# How do I get xml tag from cursor position in c# wpf textbox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have an XML text in the WPF textbox.

So for example, if the cursor is posited like this,

[image]

or like this

[image]

I want to get `tag1`. And if the cursor is located in `tag2`:

[image] I get `tag2`, and so on...

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# XML Editor - Matching XMLNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777421/c-sharp-xml-editor-matching-xmlnode)

Comment: It seems like he's asking the same question, but there is no "answer".

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define `AcceptsReturn="True"` in XAML, but I think you know that.

Then, you can use `GetLineText` method of `TextBox` in such way (I created dummy text box and event handler for purpose of presentation):

```
private void txb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle event only if Q is pressed.
    if (e.Key != Key.Q) return;
    // Count how many newline characters there were, to determine index of current line.
    var lineIndex = txb.Text.Substring(0, txb.CaretIndex).Count(ch => ch == '\n');
    // Get current line.
    var currentLine = txb.GetLineText(lineIndex);
}
```

Comment: Would this not first require a "KeyDown"? It would now provide the cursor positon until something is typed?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Yes, but it was to give an idea, not concrete implementation :) whole implementation would require error handling etc. And this site isn't for ready-to-go, fully coded solutions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, it will not work if there is an empty space before the tag or if the tag has a "child tag"  . For example           " <tag1>
<tag2>
</tag2>
(Cursor posited here)
  
</tag1>"    or   ' <tag1>
<tag2>
</tag2>
<tag3></tag2>(Cursor posited here)

</tag1>' will not work

Comment: @mohamedsherrif it was just to give you an idea how to get a line bassd on cursor position, I leave the rest up to you :)